# Factors to consider in registering an international domain

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I would like to register a ".ee" domain. I live in the US. I have checked the rules for domain registration and looks like I am able to register without issue. I would like this site to be my home on the web.

If someone looks up my name on a search engine from anywhere in the world (primarily US), would a ".ee" domain still be preferred given that the domain is registered in a different country. Wondering if search engines prioritize domains local to the search country.

Should I have concerns of the reliability of top level domain administration for relatively less popular domains like ".ee"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google prioritizes local domains over foreign ones but if does not affect the search results as much as other factors like the domain name itself.

If a person searches for "dude", `dude.ee` would likely rank over `the-one-dude.com`.
But there are hundreds of factors that affect the ranking so this is a very *theoretical* example.

Practical example: searching for "invoiceplane" as a German will mostly get you the foreign invoiceplane.com domain because it's the main site and not invoiceplane.de, which would be the site with the local domain.

---

About your concerns: only buy domains, also foreign ones, from providers you trust. If your providers do not offer the domain, I would recommend using another tld.